# Letsencrypt Certbot error

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm trying to generate a certificate on a Digital Ocean droplet running Ubuntu 12.04 following this guide: https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntuother-other

I see the following error:

> ./certbot-auto certonly
>
> ```
> ...
>
> Creating virtual environment... 
> Installing Python packages...
>
> ...
>
> copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
> copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
> copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/ciphers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
> running egg_info
> writing requirements to src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
> writing src/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
> writing top-level names to src/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
> writing dependency_links to src/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
> writing entry points to src/cryptography.egg-info/entry_points.txt
> warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found
>
> reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
> reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
> no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
> warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
> writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
> running build_ext
> generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_padding.c'
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
> generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_constant_time.c'
> generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c'
> building '_openssl' extension
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
> gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o
> build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
> gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
> Please submit a full bug report,
> with preprocessed source if appropriate.
> See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4
>
> ---------------------------------------- 
> Command "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import
> setuptools,
> tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-7RK5lP/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
> 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace(' ', ' '), __file__, 'exec'))"
> install --record /tmp/pip-sdFAkd-record/install-record.txt
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/include/site/python2.7/cryptography"
> failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-7RK5lP/cryptography 
> You are using pip version 8.0.3, however version 8.1.2 is available. 
> You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
> ```

I have successfully run this on 2 other similar servers with no issues. Any ideas?

### Edit

Found related Github issue: https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/1081

Appears to be memory related rather than Python. Attempted to stop apache service to free up memory but seeing same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The servers that I had successfully run certbot on had 2 GB memory, this one only has 512 MB, which seems to be the issue. **Added a swap file and certbot runs successfully**.

--

Certbot related issue:
https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/1081

> python-cryptography apparently tries to compile a pretty big C binding, and gcc crashes due to lack of free memory.

Used this guide to create swap space:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04