# Certbot fails to run on CentOS 6 server

Tags: python, linux, centos, centos6, lets-encrypt

I'm having some issues running the `certbot-auto` application on a CentOS 6 server, which has both Python 2.6 (`/usr/bin/python`) and 2.7 (`/usr/bin/python2.7`) installed.

A copy of the output from running `./certbot-auto` with no arguments can be found in this paste: http://pastebin.com/g7WaZUra

The error code output is *similiar* to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597326/letsencrypt-certbot-error) but my issue is almost certainly not memory related as this is a dedicated server with 32GB RAM and just a few low-traffic sites on it.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the issue, the development dependencies for Python 2.7 were missing. Fix by running `yum install python27-devel`.